# Сочинение формата ЕГЭ

Tags: общие-вопросы

Проверьте пожалуйста мое сочинение по этому тексту: https://znanija.com/task/8201963

*****В прочитанном мною рассказе, знаменитый русский писатель В. Астафьев поднимает актуальную проблему человечества о охране окружающей среды.
*****Рассказчика явно порадовала семейная пара, убирающая мусор в роще: "Они неторопливо двигались по опушке рощи, о чем-то беседуя, время от времени наклонялись и складывали в мешок бумагу, коробки от сигарет и папирос, фольгу, обрывки полиэтилена, окурки, раскисшие куски хлеба, старые обутки, лоскутье - все, чем сорит вокруг себя человек.". Такие заботливые люди особенно ценны для природы и тем более для общества. В наше время, к сожалению, большинство людей плохо обходятся с природой, не подозревая о глобальных последствиях.  Автор рассказа ставит в пример таксиста: "Видал чокнутых? - почему-то со злобой воскликнул шофер-таксист...". Об таксисте складывается мнение непонимающего человека.
*****Позиция автора в данном произведении ясна: охрана окружающей природы важна, подобные посильные и несложные действия людей могут существенно помочь состоянию природы. В первую очередь это показывает их образованность, автор  сравнивает таксиста с академиком.
*****Я полностью согласен с автором и не только я. Каждый может внести свой посильный вклад в охрану окружающей среды!  Данным вопросом озабоченны во всех цивилизованных странах, от состояния природы  зависит жизнь каждого человека.
*****Недавние события произошедшие в Чернобыле,  очень пагубно повлияли на состояние природы, более масштабной экологической аварии человечество еще не видело. Все страны были заинтересованы в устранении ужасных последствий.
*****Немало поучительных сказок на тему охраны окружающей среды есть в русской литературе. Например в повести В. Астафьева "Царь рыба" рассказывается об умелом рыбаке Игнатыче, ловившем рыбу в непомерных количествах, наносившем вред природе. Однажды он встречается с самым ценным и запретным уловом "царь рыбой". Пренебрегая правилами, он решается ее уловить, а в процессе ловли падает в свои же снасти с рыбой: «Реки царь и всей природы царь — на одной ловушке». Рыбак понимает, что все его несчастья в жизни связаны только  с браконьерством, природа его так проучила.
*****Если мы будем бережно относится к природе, то уровень жизни людей на планете повысится в разы. Каждый человек ответственен за состояние природы.

PS: Я так и не смог сделать правильно отступ, вместо него 5 звездочек. Всего 313 слов.

Comment: На сайте не занимаются проверкой сочинений. Пожалуйста, обратитесь к специалистам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В квадратных скобках - то, что требует исправления, в фигурных - исправления и комментарии.

*****В прочитанном мною рассказе[,] {**запятая не нужна**} знаменитый русский писатель В. Астафьев поднимает [актуальную проблему человечества о охране окружающей среды] {**актуальную для человечества проблему охраны окружающей среды**}.

*****Рассказчика явно порадовала семейная пара, убирающая мусор в роще: "Они неторопливо двигались по опушке рощи, о чем-то беседуя, время от времени наклонялись и складывали в мешок бумагу, коробки от сигарет и папирос, фольгу, обрывки полиэтилена, окурки, раскисшие куски хлеба, старые обутки, лоскутье - все, чем сорит вокруг себя человек[.]{**Точка ставится после кавычек**}". Такие заботливые люди особенно ценны для природы и тем более для общества. В наше время, к сожалению, большинство людей плохо обходятся с природой, не подозревая о глобальных последствиях. Автор рассказа [ставит] {**приводит**} в пример таксиста: "Видал чокнутых? - почему-то со злобой воскликнул шофер-таксист..."[.]{ **Многоточие стоит перед закрывающей кавычкой — точка после кавычек в этом случае не нужна**} [Об]{**O**} таксисте складывается мнение [непонимающего человека] {, **что он не понимает, зачем нужно заботиться о природе**}.

*****Позиция автора в данном произведении ясна: охрана окружающей природы важна, подобные посильные и несложные действия людей могут существенно помочь [состоянию природы]{**природе**}. [В первую очередь это показывает их образованность, автор сравнивает таксиста с академиком.] {**Смысл не ясен. Требует переделки. Например: Во многом это зависит от образованности людей (автор сравнивает таксиста с академиком).}**

*****Я полностью согласен с автором{**,}** и не только я. Каждый может внести свой посильный вклад в охрану окружающей среды! Данным вопросом [озабоченны] {**озабочены**} во всех цивилизованных странах, от состояния природы зависит жизнь каждого человека.

*****Недавние события{**,}** произошедшие в Чернобыле, очень пагубно повлияли на состояние природы, более масштабной экологической [аварии] {**катастрофы**} человечество еще не видело. Все страны были заинтересованы в устранении ужасных последствий.

*****Немало поучительных сказок на тему [охраны окружающей среды] {**сказки в основном старинные, а термин современный, лучше: заботы о природе**} есть в русской литературе. Например{**,}** в повести В. Астафьева "Царь{-}рыба" рассказывается об умелом рыбаке [Игнатыче] {**Игнатьиче**}, ловившем рыбу в непомерных количествах[,] **{и этим}** наносившем вред природе. Однажды он встречается с самым ценным и запретным уловом **{—}** "царь{-}рыбой". Пренебрегая правилами, он решается ее [уловить]{**поймать**}, [а] {**но**} в процессе ловли падает в свои же снасти {**вместе**} с рыбой: «Реки царь и всей природы царь — на одной ловушке». Рыбак понимает, что все [его] несчастья в {**его**} жизни связаны только с браконьерством, природа его так проучила.

{**Я с таким пониманием не согласен. По-моему, повесть Астафьева — не сказка, и она вовсе не на тему охраны природы**}

*****Если мы будем бережно [относится] {**относиться**} к природе, то уровень жизни людей на планете повысится в разы. Каждый человек ответственен за состояние природы.

Comment: Титанический труд!  Не знаю: можно ли оценивать? - ведь вопрос-то "завернут".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова оценивайте конечно, переоткрыл даже.

Comment: Дополнительная правка: "царь-рыба" пишется через дефис.

Comment: @МаркИз насколько мне известно, голосовать можно за любые вопросы, кроме заблокированных